# Importing dayjs in "ng library" outputs namespace error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make my own DateAdapter implementation so that I don't have to import *moment.js* (that is about half of project size), but instead import *dayjs* which is almost the same many times lighter.

I compared the library to *moment* and *date-fns* , where there is a workaround doing this:

```
import * as moment_ from 'moment';
const moment = moment_;
```

Tried the same with dayjs, no luck.

Tried modifying the library index.d.ts default exports, same with other errors.

In the example code provided, the error is:

> Cannot call a namespace ('dayjs')

```
import { Inject, Injectable, Optional, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { DateAdapter } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatDateFormats, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';

import * as dayjs from 'dayjs';
import 'dayjs/locale/es';
/** Configurable options for {@see DayjsDateAdapter}. */
export interface DayjsDateAdapterOptions {
    /**
     * Turns the use of utc dates on or off.
     * Changing this will change how Angular Material components like DatePicker output dates.
     * {@default false}
     */
    useUtc: boolean;
}

export const DAYJS_DATE_FORMATS: MatDateFormats = {
    parse: {
        dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    },
    display: {
        dateInput: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        monthYearLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
        dateA11yLabel: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    },
};

/** InjectionToken for dayjs date adapter to configure options. */
export const DAYJS_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS = new InjectionToken<DayjsDateAdapterOptions>(
    'DAYJS_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS', {
        providedIn: 'root',
        factory: DAYJS_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS_FACTORY
    });


/** @docs-private */
export function DAYJS_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS_FACTORY(): DayjsDateAdapterOptions {
    return {
        useUtc: false
    };
}


/** Creates an array and fills it with values. */
function range<T>(length: number, valueFunction: (index: number) => T): T[] {
    const valuesArray = Array(length);
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        valuesArray[i] = valueFunction(i);
    }
    return valuesArray;
}

/** Adapts dayjs Dates for use with Angular Material. */
@Injectable()
export class DayjsDateAdapter extends DateAdapter<dayjs.Dayjs> {
    // Note: all of the methods that accept a `dayjs` input parameter immediately call `this.clone`
    // on it. This is to ensure that we're working with a `dayjs` that has the correct locale setting
    // while avoiding mutating the original object passed to us. Just calling `.locale(...)` on the
    // input would mutate the object.

    private _localeData: {
        firstDayOfWeek: number,
        longMonths: string[],
        shortMonths: string[],
        dates: string[],
        longDaysOfWeek: string[],
        shortDaysOfWeek: string[],
        narrowDaysOfWeek: string[]
    };

    constructor(
        @Optional() @Inject(MAT_DATE_LOCALE) dateLocale: string,
        @Optional() @Inject(DAYJS_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS) private options?: DayjsDateAdapterOptions
    ) {
        super();
        this.setLocale(dateLocale);
    }

    setLocale(locale: string) {
        super.setLocale(locale);
        this._localeData = {
            firstDayOfWeek: 0,
            longMonths: 'Enero_Febrero_Marzo_Abril_Mayo_Junio_Julio_Agosto_Septiembre_Octubre_Noviembre_Diciembre'.split('_'),
            shortMonths: 'enero_feb_marzo_abr_mayo_jun_jul_agosto_sept_oct_nov_dic'.split('_'),
            dates: range(31, (i) => this.createDate(2017, 0, i + 1).format('D')),
            longDaysOfWeek: 'Domingo_Lunes_Martes_Miércoles_Jueves_Viernes_Sábado'.split('_'),
            shortDaysOfWeek: 'Dom_Lun_Mar_Mié_Jue_Vie_Sáb'.split('_'),
            narrowDaysOfWeek: 'Do_Lu_Ma_Mi_Ju_Vi_Sá'.split('_'),
        };
    }

    getYear(date: dayjs.Dayjs): number {
        return this.clone(date).year();
    }

    getMonth(date: dayjs.Dayjs): number {
        return this.clone(date).month();
    }

    getDate(date: dayjs.Dayjs): number {
        return this.clone(date).date();
    }

    getDayOfWeek(date: dayjs.Dayjs): number {
        return this.clone(date).day();
    }

    getMonthNames(style: 'long' | 'short' | 'narrow'): string[] {
        // dayjs.js doesn't support narrow month names, so we just use short if narrow is requested.
        return style === 'long' ? this._localeData.longMonths : this._localeData.shortMonths;
    }

    getDateNames(): string[] {
        return this._localeData.dates;
    }

    getDayOfWeekNames(style: 'long' | 'short' | 'narrow'): string[] {
        if (style === 'long') {
            return this._localeData.longDaysOfWeek;
        }
        if (style === 'short') {
            return this._localeData.shortDaysOfWeek;
        }
        return this._localeData.narrowDaysOfWeek;
    }

    getYearName(date: dayjs.Dayjs): string {
        return this.clone(date).format('YYYY');
    }

    getFirstDayOfWeek(): number {
        return this._localeData.firstDayOfWeek;
    }

    getNumDaysInMonth(date: dayjs.Dayjs): number {
        return this.clone(date).daysInMonth();
    }

    clone(date: dayjs.Dayjs): dayjs.Dayjs {
        return date.clone().locale(this.locale);
    }

    createDate(year: number, month: number, date: number): dayjs.Dayjs {
        // dayjs.js will create an invalid date if any of the components are out of bounds, but we
        // explicitly check each case so we can throw more descriptive errors.
        if (month < 0 || month > 11) {
            throw Error(`Invalid month index "${month}". Month index has to be between 0 and 11.`);
        }
        if (date < 1) {
            throw Error(`Invalid date "${date}". Date has to be greater than 0.`);
        }
        const result = this._createDayjs({ year, month, date });
        // If the result isn't valid, the date must have been out of bounds for this month.
        if (!result.isValid()) {
            throw Error(`Invalid date "${date}" for month with index "${month}".`);
        }
        return result;
    }

    today(): dayjs.Dayjs {
        return this._createDayjs();
    }

    parse(value: any, parseFormat: string | string[]): dayjs.Dayjs | null {
        if (value && typeof value === 'string') {
            return this._createDayjs(value).locale(this.locale);
        }
        return value ? this._createDayjs(value).locale(this.locale) : null;
    }

    format(date: dayjs.Dayjs, displayFormat: string): string {
        date = this.clone(date);
        if (!this.isValid(date)) {
            throw Error('DayjsDateAdapter: Cannot format invalid date.');
        }
        return date.format(displayFormat);
    }

    addCalendarYears(date: dayjs.Dayjs, years: number): dayjs.Dayjs {
        return this.clone(date).add(years, 'year');
    }

    addCalendarMonths(date: dayjs.Dayjs, months: number): dayjs.Dayjs {
        return this.clone(date).add(months, 'month');
    }

    addCalendarDays(date: dayjs.Dayjs, days: number): dayjs.Dayjs {
        return this.clone(date).add(days, 'day');
    }

    toIso8601(date: dayjs.Dayjs): string {
        return this.clone(date).toISOString();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the given value if given a valid dayjs or null. Deserializes valid ISO 8601 strings
     * (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) and valid Date objects into valid dayjss and empty
     * string into null. Returns an invalid date for all other values.
     */
    deserialize(value: any): dayjs.Dayjs | null {
        let date;
        if (value instanceof Date) {
            date = this._createDayjs(value).locale(this.locale);
        } else if (this.isDateInstance(value)) {
            // Note: assumes that cloning also sets the correct locale.
            return this.clone(value);
        }
        if (typeof value === 'string') {
            if (!value) {
                return null;
            }
            date = this._createDayjs(value).locale(this.locale);
        }
        if (date && this.isValid(date)) {
            return this._createDayjs(date).locale(this.locale);
        }
        return super.deserialize(value);
    }

    isDateInstance(obj: any): boolean {
        return dayjs.isDayjs(obj);
    }

    isValid(date: dayjs.Dayjs): boolean {
        return this.clone(date).isValid();
    }

    invalid(): dayjs.Dayjs {
        return dayjs(null);
    }

    /** Creates a dayjs instance */
    private _createDayjs(args?: any): dayjs.Dayjs {
        if (dayjs.isDayjs(args)) {
            return this.clone(args);
        } else if (args instanceof Date) {
            return this.clone(dayjs(args));
        } else {
            let djs = dayjs();
            let key: any;
            for (key in args) {
                if (args.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    djs = djs.set(key, args[key]);
                }
            }
            return this.clone(djs);
        }
    }
}
```

I almost replicated the moment date adapter from material2 [GitHub repository](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/material-moment-adapter/adapter) so I have no clue, and guess it's a dayjs issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it's a bit old but I had a similar issue today. 
I believe from the version 1.8.10 and above you can now load it with:

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
```

I have 1.8.15 and it's working fine now.

Comment: Thanks for replying, could be helpful!

Comment: you have to set allowSyntheticDefaultImports : true in your tsConfig.json to allow use dayjs